# Cannot connect Oracle database in code but ok with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, connection-string, oledb

I'm developping a small application which have to connect on an Oracle Database.

With SSMS no problem. So i get the connection string from the properties :

```
Data Source=myserver;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True
```

When I try to connect with VB.NET with Framework 4.5 :

```
Public testdb As New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myserver;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True")
testdb.Open()
```

I get the following error :

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>    Attribute Invalid connection string

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why sqloledb provider? Try with oraoledb, or msdaora.

Comment: sqloledb doesn't work but ok with oraoledb. Thanks to you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing provider to **msdaora** solved the issue.

Thanks to dean for the solution.